# Construct user defined map in Go

Tags: dictionary, go

I want to create map which stores routes from one point to another, distance between them will be used as values in the map.

```
type Route struct {
    start  string
    finish string
}

m := make(map[Route]int)
v := Route{start: "A",
            finish: "B"}
m[v] = 42
```

Distance from A to B equals to distance from B to A.

```
w := Route{start: "B",
        finish: "A"}
```

How can I get `m[w]` without pushing `m[w] = 42` into the map again because `v` and `w` are the same route.

P.S In other words, is it possible to override rules when one `Route` equals to another `Route` when using `Route` as a key in map?

Comment: You cannot. Or use comma-okay to see if B-->A is in the map and query A-->B if not.

Comment: They may be the same route or distance but they are not the same `Route`. You need to come up with a type that is the same for both.

Comment: Is it possible to override the rules when one `Route` equals to another `Route`?

Comment: No. Equality is a fixed language construct and not user definable.

Answer (score 2):

Define `map[Route]int` as a user-defined type like `RouteDistance`.

```
type RouteDistance map[Route]int
```

And then define a `Find` function on that type, to check for bi-directional routes and return the distance.

```
func (rd RouteDistance) Find(r Route) (d int, ok bool) {
    routeDistance := map[Route]int(rd)
    d, ok = routeDistance[r]
    if ok {
        return
    }
    d, ok = routeDistance[Route{start: r.finish, finish: r.start}]
    if ok {
        return
    }
    return -1, false
}
```

Initiate the `RouteDistance` with just one-directional route and distance.

```
rd := make(RouteDistance)
rd[Route{start: "A", finish: "B"}] = 42
```

Get bi-directional distance for routes.

```
rd.Find(Route{start: "A", finish: "B"})
rd.Find(Route{start: "B", finish: "A"})
```

The working code is in [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/sOqmxgxEhCh)

Comment: This line `routeDistance := map[Route]int(rd)` is unneeded, you can index `rd` just like a normal map.

Answer (score 1):

Index the map with a `Route` where `finish` and `start` are swapped:

```
m[Route{start: w.finish, finish: w.start}]
```

If you want to check both directions, create a helper function for it:

```
var m = make(map[Route]int)

func dist(r Route) int {
    if d, ok := m[r]; ok {
        return d
    }
    return m[Route{start: r.finish, finish: r.start}]
}
```

Note that `dist()` will return `0` if neither direction is in the map. If you want to return this info too:

```
func dist(r Route) (d int, found bool) {
    d, found = m[r]
    if !found {
        d, found = m[Route{start: r.finish, finish: r.start}]
    }
    return
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/BHPSHp8f8Er).

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to do this without pushing an additional value. Either perform two map accesses:

```
r := Route{
    start: "B",
    finish: "A",
}
d, ok := m[r]
if !ok {
    r.start = "B"
    r.finish = "A"
    d, ok = m[r]
}
if !ok {
    // value not found
}
```

Or for every map store and access, sort the `start` and `finish`:

```
func Put(start, finish string, d int) {
    r := Route{start, finish}
    if start > finish {
        r.start = finish
        r.finish = start
    }
    m[r] = d
}

func Get(r Route) int {
    if r.start > r.finish {
        r.start, r.finish = r.finish, r.start
    }
    m[r] = d
}
```